# How to Reset Netsuite Administration Role / Delete all Customization in Netsuite Account

Tags: netsuite

Is this possible to delete all customization from the Netsuite account? Just Like we reset Window or Android Systems and it deletes all applications and Information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all customisation ( forms, settings, installed bundles, custom roles) and data (transactions, entities, custom record data), raise a case with support. It's something that they can arrange.